# cannot open session or publish post to facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

For some reason the pffacebookutils session does not open/remain open.
I cannot publish to facebook and am getting this error. I assure you the currentuser is linked with facebook.

```
if ([[PFFacebookUtils session] isOpen]) {
        /*
         * if the current session has no publish permission we need to reauthorize
         */
        if ([[[PFFacebookUtils session] permissions]indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {

            [[PFFacebookUtils session] requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                                    defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,NSError *error){
                                                      [self publishFacebookStory: object message:message];
                                                  }];

        }else{
            [self publishFacebookStory: object message:message];
        }
    }else{
        /*
         * open a new session with publish permission
         */
        [[PFFacebookUtils session] openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && status == FBSessionStateOpen) {
                [self publishFacebookStory: object message:message];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"%@",error);
            }
        }];
}
```

Some related error output:

- FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint '/me/fitness.runs': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.
- Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x17547aa80 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
  body =     {
      error =         {
          code = 2500;
          message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
          type = OAuthException;
      };
  };
  code = 400;
  }}
- PFKeychainStore failed to get object for key 'currentUser'

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was temporarily fixed, and I actually no longer recall what the actual issue was...but I now use parse facebook utils v4 and facebook sdk 4.0+ and the issue no longer exists because there is no such thing as sessions anymore.